# mysql error 1064 stored procedure extract json value into specific columns in table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I want to extract json data of variable length into an existing table, but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin declare len int; declare i int; declare mykey varchar(60); declare myvalue' at line 2

Does anyone know how to solve this error or how to extract json data of variable length into an existing table?

This is my code:

```
drop procedure if exists wk; 
delimiter //　
create procedure wk(tb varchar(60), myjson json)　　　
begin
SET @LEN= (select JSON_LENGTH(myjson));
set @i=1;
set @mykey='initial';
set @myvalue='initial';
set @thekeys= (select JSON_keys(myjson));
set @mysql_1=concat("insert into ",tb," (");
set @mysql_2='(';
while @i < @len*2 do
select 3;
set @mykey = (select substring(substring_index(@thekeys,'"',@i+1),length(substring_index(@thekeys,'"',@i))+2));
set @myvalue = (select json_extract(myjson,concat('$.',@mykey)));
set @mysql_1= concat(@mysql, @mykey,","); 
set @mysql_2= concat(@mysql_2, @myvalue,",") ;
set @i =@i+2
end while;

set @mysql = concat(substring(@mysql_1,-1),") values ", substring(@mysql_2,-1)," );");

PREPARE stmt FROM @mysql;
EXECUTE stmt;

end
  //
delimiter ;

call wk('actor','{"actor_id": 1, "first_name": "NICK"}');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of the errors appear to be some non-printing characters at the second and third lines of your procedure - directly after `delimiter //`, and also after the closing bracket of `create procedure wk(tb varchar(60), myjson json)`.

Once you clear those characters you'll get another error which will tell you there is another syntax error immediately before `end while` (missing semi-colon after `set @i =@i+2`).

MySQL is usually very good at letting you know exactly where it starts to run into problems when attempting to parse your statements, with the issue directly preceding the highlighted text. Here, it says the problem starts at 'begin' and the problem is directly before it.

With the errors out of the way, your procedure will then run and output "3" twice. However, @mysql will be NULL and no statement will be prepared and executed.

I'm not going to attempt to debug the code because I think you are over-complicating the problem. You seem to be trying to write your own routines to parse parts of the JSON when MySQL has perfectly good tools to do it for you. Setting @mykey is a case in point, where you could use an index directly into the @thekeys array rather than using substring to parse out the keys e.g.

```
mysql> SET @thekeys = JSON_KEYS('{"actor_id": 1, "first_name": "NICK"}');

mysql> SET @mykey = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@thekeys, '$[1]'));

mysql> SELECT @mykey;
+------------+
| @mykey     |
+------------+
| first_name |
+------------+
```

If you use the built-in JSON functions you can make the code much simpler, then all you have to worry about is whether your key value pairs match the defined column names and data types.

e.g.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS wk //
CREATE PROCEDURE wk(tbl VARCHAR(64), myjson JSON)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET @keys = '';
  SET @vals = '';

  WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(myjson) DO
    SET @mykey = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(myjson), CONCAT('$[', i, ']')));
    SET @myval = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(myjson, CONCAT('$.', @mykey)));

    SET @keys = CONCAT(@keys, IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@keys) > 0, ',', ''),
      CONCAT('`', @mykey, '`')); 
    SET @vals = CONCAT(@vals, IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@vals) > 0, ',', ''),
      CONCAT('''', @myval, ''''));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `', tbl , '`(', @keys, ') VALUES (', @vals, ');');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;    

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL wk('actor','{"actor_id": 1, "first_name": "NICK"}');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. actually, the reason i didn't use built-in JSON functions is that i wouldn't know which fields i would get from the json in advance. the fileds can be of variable length. For example, I could get five fields in json and insert the values into corresponding columns in table. But i don't which five fields before i read the json.

Comment: @chunguanghe If try this method you'll see that the number of elements in the JSON string doesn't matter, nor which fields they refer to, because the WHILE loop will just keep processing them in turn until it runs out of key/value pairs.